# how to fix "unable to find method 'getConstants()'" in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

good day everyone,

I'm working on a react native project and I just installed the `react-native-navigation` module and followed the instructions provided by the documentation.

I did a `gradlew clean` to clean the app before starting. once I started the app I get a blank screen on the android emulator and a warning message in the console of js debugger window.

> Unable to define method 'getConstants()' on NativeModule 'RNNBridgeModule'. NativeModule 'RNNBridgeModule' already has a constant or method called 'getConstants'. Please remove it.

this is the warning I keep getting with nothing wrong shows in the metro server console open in the terminal.

this is the components i created so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import { colors, fontSizes, dimensions } from '../../styles/base.js';
import showToast from '../generic/Toast';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.login}>
        <Image 
          source={require('../../img/logo.png')}
          style={styles.img}
          resizeMode="contain"
          resizeMethod="scale"
        />
        <TextInput

          onChange={uname => this.setState({ username: uname })}
          placeholder={"Username"}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChange={pwd =>
            this.setState({
              password: pwd
            })
          }
          placeholder={"Password"}
          style={[styles.input, styles.password]}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />
        < TouchableOpacity onPress = {
          () => {/*showToast({
            msg: dimensions.fl + " " + dimensions.fw
          })*/
          console.log("height: "+ dimensions.fl);
          console.log("width: "+ dimensions.fw);
          }} >
          <Text style={styles.btn}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("settings...")} style={styles.iconBtn}>
          <Icon name="settings" size={35} style={styles.icon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let width,mbi,mtb,mtp;
if(dimensions.fw <= 568) {
  width = "90%";
  mbi = 10;
  mtb = 15;
  mtp = 10;
  fontSize = fontSizes.textSizeSmall;
} else if (dimensions.fw > 586 && dimensions.fw <= 768) {
  width = "80%";
  mbi = 20;
  mtb = 25;
  mtp = 20;
  fontSize = fontSizes.textSizeMedium;
} else if (dimensions.fw > 768) {
  width = "65%";
  mbi = 60;
  mtb = 35;
  mtp = 30;
  fontSize = fontSizes.textSizeLarge
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  login: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.sky
  },
  input: {
    height: 55,
    width,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: colors.red,
    fontSize
  },
  password: {
    marginTop: mtp
  },
  btn: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    paddingLeft: 40,
    paddingRight: 40,
    color: colors.light,
    backgroundColor: colors.darksky,
    fontSize,
    marginTop: mtb
  },
  img: {
    width: "80%",
    height: "50%",
    marginBottom: mbi,
    marginTop: "-8%"
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: 25,
    marginBottom: 15,
    color: colors.dark
  },
  iconBtn: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';

export default showToast = (props) => {
    return Toast.show(props.msg, {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
        shadow: true,
        hideOnPress: true,
        animation: true,
        delay: 500,
        backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor || "black",
        shadowColor: props.shadowColor || "gray",
        textColor: props.textColor || "white",
        containerStyle: {
            width: "100%",
            borderRadius: 0,
            paddingBottom: 10
        }
    })
}
```

I was hoping one of you have an answer to this problem because I didn't really find anything that resembles this in the last hour of searching.

thanks, everyone for your time and advice.

Comment: can you add code where you are getting this warning ?

Comment: well i'll add the component i have but it's alot of code because i installed the package after i already developed a screen

Comment: have your followed the installation steps properly ? What is your react native version ? and have you tried running in IOS ?

Comment: i have rn v 0.59.3 and i don't have mac to try for ios. and yes i followed the steps to the letter

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue on `react-native-navigation 3.5.1` and `RN 0.61.4`. Have you found a working solution?

Comment: Hi, I am having same warning on both android and ios, did you find the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chawki challadia along the latest versions of react-navigation you need to install gesture handler also(npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler) which is mentioned in here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html. That's why you are getting the warning. Also don't forget to link the gesture handler library with react-native link react-native-gesture-handler. It should work fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm using react-natuve-navigation that's react-navigation. not the same library

Answer (score 1):

In my case create a new rn project and i followed https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing instructions, but without replacing versions in build.gradle and it works for my